# Apple Music checked as disabled and grayed out in iTunes

Tags: itunes, high-sierra, apple-music

In iTunes' preferences pane for Restrictions, Apple Music is grayed out and checked as disabled. Any idea how to enable this? The lock is not engaged at the bottom.

[image: Apple Music grayed out]

Comment: Is you Mac online? Are you signed in into Apple Music?

Comment: @nohillside Online and signed into the Apple ID that has my Apple Music. Can't find any interface for signing into Apple Music and wasn't prompted when I first opened iTunes.

Comment: Did you tried to close/open again your iTunes session (menu > accounts)? Additionally check if it is not your entire session that is restricted via Parental Control (in Mac Settings).

Comment: @LouisLac I tried logging in and out, as well as deauthorizing and re-authorizing. User account is admin and not restricted in Parental Control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I had a Device Profile created by my administrator which disabled Apple Music, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have some custom "Profile" in your Mac try to remove it.

1. check your "Profiles" list (in terminal) `sudo profiles list`.
2. `sudo profiles remove -identifier (identifier from the previous step)`.